# How to parameterize electron's autoUpdater notification

Tags: electron

How can I parameterize electron's autoUpdater notification so it only displays the producName from the package.json instead of electron.app.productName in windows?

eg:

autoUpdater Notification:

[image: autoUpdater notifications]

versus regular notification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue in the autoUpdater notification I added:

```
app.setAppUserModelId('MY_PRODUCT_NAME')
```

and it removed the 'electron.app' prefix